# How to order a list with nav?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a way of ordering a list into specific sections using a nav bar. For example, all list items displays under 'All' and then the option to refine the list into 3 other sections.

Current example
https://ibb.co/pvBV4Lf

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? Any examples?
I'm not even sure what you would name this kind of function

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#"><h1>All</h1></a>
    <a href="#"><h1><span>Residential</span></h1></a>
    <a href="#"><h1><span>Commercial</span></h1></a>
    <a href="#"><h1><span>Retail</span></h1></a>
</div> 

<ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Granville Place</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>Palisade</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>King &amp; Phillip</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>Castle Residences</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>Opera Residences</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>Brighton Collection</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>Carpe Group</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>The Lennox</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>South Quarter</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>One Barangaroo</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>One Queensbridge</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>Australia 108</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>Oceans Freshwater</li></a><br>
        <a href="#"><li>The Pavilions</li></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow,

one way to filter your list element is to append a `data-*` attribute to your elements and bind a javascript function on your links in the `div.nav` to filter the list:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // filter list
    const filterList = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // fetch filtertype
        const type = e.target.closest('a').getAttribute('data-filter-type');
        // hide or display list elements
        document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(li => {
            li.style.display = type === li.getAttribute('data-filter-type') || type === 'all' ? 'list-item' : 'none';
        });
    };

    // bind links
    document.querySelectorAll('.nav a').forEach(a => {
        a.addEventListener('click', filterList)
    });
});
```

```css
h1 { font-size: 18px; }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#" data-filter-type="all"><h1>All</h1></a>
    <a href="#" data-filter-type="residential"><h1><span>Residential</span></h1></a>
    <a href="#" data-filter-type="commercial"><h1><span>Commercial</span></h1></a>
    <a href="#" data-filter-type="retail"><h1><span>Retail</span></h1></a>
</div>

<ul>
    <li data-filter-type="residential"><a href="#">Granville Place</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="residential"><a href="#">Palisade</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="commercial"><a href="#">King &amp; Phillip</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="commercial"><a href="#">Castle Residences</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="residential"><a href="#">Opera Residences</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="residential"><a href="#">Brighton Collection</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="commercial"><a href="#">Carpe Group</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="retail"><a href="#">The Lennox</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="retail"><a href="#">South Quarter</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="residential"><a href="#">One Barangaroo</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="residential"><a href="#">One Queensbridge</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="retail"><a href="#">Australia 108</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="commercial"><a href="#">Oceans Freshwater</a></li>
    <li data-filter-type="commercial"><a href="#">The Pavilions</a>
</ul>
```